# Triple integral - why do I have to divide the area into two sub-areas?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

So suppose we have to calculate $$\iiint V\, \mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dz,$$ where $z=6-x^2-y^2$, $z^2=x^2+y^2$, $z=0$.

I plugged the equations in GeoGebra so I have a fairly good concept of what the required area is, but the solution of the integral states that we have to divide the area into two sub-areas $V_1$ and $V_2$, so that:

$V_1 : 0 \le z \le \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

$V_2 : 0 \le z \le 6-x^2-y^2$

However, I fail to see why we need to break up the integral in the first place. Why do we do that? Couldn't we just have introduced cylindrical coordinates for the whole integral?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $V=$ the triple integral?  Then $z=6-x^2-y^2$ gives a parabaloid and $z=0$ cuts off a volume.  How does $z^2=x^2+y^2$ enter into the problem?

Comment: You have not stated your problem correctly. This is not how your represent bounds of a region for volume integral. You are talking about volume bound between surfaces, probably only above $XY$ plane. Be specific. Have you visualized the surfaces? What have you understood so far of the region?

Comment: @MathLover Perhaps I have made a mistake, I am new to double/triple integrals. Yes I have visualized the surfaces and checked my visualisation in GeoGebra. Well, I don't know if I had anything specific to notice.

Comment: @MathLover yes sorry I edited my comment